# Como simular as funções LEAD e LAG? [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

Estive desenvolvendo recentemente uma query na qual me surgiu a necessidade de *comparar sucessivamente as linhas de um mesmo conjunto de dados*, quero dizer, de uma mesma coluna, de uma mesma tabela. Nisto, tomei conhecimento das funções LEAD() e LAG() do MySQL. Entretanto, verifiquei mais tarde que essas são funções do tipo "funções de janela" e que talvez elas não estejam disponíveis para MySQL. Dai a pergunta: é possível simular seu funcionamento?

1. [MySQL e as Funções de Janela](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions) 
    Discussão a respeito das "Funções de Janela" e sua indisponibilidade no MySQL.
2. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa088a/1) (A query que estive  desenvolvendo): 
   A query busca retornar em colunas distintas, com base no seu ***valor*** de registro (binário), os momentos em que os registros estiveram em 0 e em 1. E a partir disso, verificar o intervalo entre eles. Para isso "desconsiderando" a data fornecida pelo timestamp e convertendo o período que antes em formato HH:MM:SS para somente horas.
3. Simulate  [LAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql) and [LEAD](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187933/simulate-effective-lead1-or-lead2-in-mysql?newreg=afcb2753476e48b99584e965f5864f4e) Function: 
   Encontrei um post semelhante no StackOverflow e Database Administrator, entretanto verifiquei que não havia nada a respeito por aqui, além do que, não consegui aplicar a resposta ao meu caso. Dai enxerguei a necessidade de abrir uma pergunta.
4. [Função LEAD - MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) (Resumo sobre a a função LEAD)
   A função LEAD() é uma **função de janela** que permite procurar um número de linhas e acessar dados dessa linha a partir da linha atual. Semelhante a função LAG(), a função LEAD() é muito útil para o cálculo da diferença entre a linha corrente e a linha subsequente dentro do mesmo conjunto de resultados.

Exemplo:

```
mysql> SELECT
             t, val,
             LEAD(val)       OVER w AS 'lead',
             val - LEAD(val) OVER w AS 'lead diff'
           FROM series
           WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY t);
    +----------+------+------+--------- -+
    | t        | val  | lead | lead diff |
    +----------+------+------+-----------+
    | 12:00:00 |  100 |  125 |       -25 |
    | 13:00:00 |  125 |  132 |        -7 |
    | 14:00:00 |  132 |  145 |       -13 |
    | 15:00:00 |  145 |  140 |         5 |
    | 16:00:00 |  140 |  150 |       -10 |
    | 17:00:00 |  150 |  200 |       -50 |
    | 18:00:00 |  200 | NULL |      NULL |
    +----------+------+------+-----------+
```

---

**EDIÇÃO 1:**
Eu espero atingir um resultado semelhante a isso:

```
        +----------+----------+---------------+----------+----------+---------------+
        | t p/ v=1 | lead v=1 | lead diff v=1 | t p/ v=0 | lead v=0 | lead diff v=0 |
        +----------+----------+---------------+----------+----------+---------------+
        | 20.8806  | (null)   | (null)        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        |    
        | 20.8764  | 20.8806  | -0,0042       | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        |    
        | 20.87    | 20.8764  | -0,0064       | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        |   
        | 20.8636  | 20.87    | -0,0064       | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        |  
        | 20.8508  | 20.8636  | -0,0128       | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        |  
        | 20.85    | 20.8508  | -0,0008       | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 
        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 20.8333  | (null)   | (null)        |   
        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 20.8303  | 20.8333  | -0,003        |
        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 20.83    | 20.8303  | -0,003        |
        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 20.8     | 20.83    | -0,03         |
        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 20.5     | 20.8     | -0,3          |
        | (null)   | (null)   | (null)        | 20.4964  | 20.5     | -0,0036       |
        +----------+-----------+--------------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

- A coluna ***lead v=n*** desloca-se uma linha em referência a coluna a sua esquerda ***t p/ v=n***
- A coluna ***lead diff v=n*** calcula a diferença entre as outras duas colunas

Comment: Pode actualizar a pergunta mostrando um exemplo do resultado que deseja obter?

Comment: Feito @bruno. Acredita que é de alguma utilidade ou bastaria ter respondido que desejo um resultado semelhante ao exemplo?

Comment: Sim, a sua edição é bastante útil. Mostrando o resultado que pretende obter, fica mais fácil para a comunidade ajudar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem várias alternativas simples de simular as funções LEAD() e LAG() em MySQL.

Usando o seu Fiddle como base

```
CREATE TABLE Teste
    (`Time_Stamp` varchar(20) ,`valor` int(2))
;

INSERT INTO Teste
    (`Time_Stamp`,`Valor`)
VALUES
    ('2018-11-23 20:23:10','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:24:20','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:24:34','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:25:30','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:26:40','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:28:01','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:28:56','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:29:22','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:29:47','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:30:00','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:48:00','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:49:49','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:49:48','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:50:00','0'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:51:00','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:51:03','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:51:49','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:52:12','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:52:35','1'),
    ('2018-11-23 20:52:50','1')
;
```

Uma alternativa consiste em ligar a tabela a si própria usando uma sequência. Penso que esta query irá devolver o resultado pretendido.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN T1.Valor = 1 THEN T1.Horas END AS 't p/ v=1',
       CASE WHEN T1.Valor = 1 THEN T_LEAD.Horas END AS 'lead v=1',
       CASE WHEN T1.Valor = 1 THEN T1.Horas - T_LEAD.Horas END AS 'lead diff v=1',
       CASE WHEN T1.Valor = 0 THEN T1.Horas END AS 't p/ v=0',
       CASE WHEN T1.Valor = 0 AND T_LEAD.Valor = 0 THEN T_LEAD.Horas END AS 'lead v=0',
       CASE WHEN T1.Valor = 0 AND T_LEAD.Valor = 0 THEN T1.Horas - T_LEAD.Horas END AS 'lead diff v=0'
  FROM 
  ( 
      SELECT Time_Stamp, 
             (HOUR(CAST(time_stamp AS TIME)) + (MINUTE(CAST(time_stamp AS TIME)) / 60) + SECOND(CAST(time_stamp AS TIME)) / 3600) AS Horas, 
             Valor, 
             @seq1 := @seq1 + 1 AS Seq 
        FROM Teste, (SELECT @seq1 := 0) r 
       ORDER BY Time_Stamp, Valor
  ) T1
  LEFT JOIN 
  ( 
     SELECT Time_Stamp, 
            (HOUR(CAST(time_stamp AS TIME)) + (MINUTE(CAST(time_stamp AS TIME)) / 60) + SECOND(CAST(time_stamp AS TIME)) / 3600) AS Horas, 
            Valor, 
            @seq3 := @seq3 + 1 AS Seq 
       FROM Teste, (SELECT @seq3 := 0) r 
      ORDER BY Time_Stamp, Valor
  ) T_LEAD
    ON T_LEAD.Seq - 1 = T1.Seq
 WHERE CAST(T1.time_stamp AS DATE) = '2018-11-23'
ORDER BY T1.time_stamp DESC;
```

Fica aqui o [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa088a/32) para testar

As primeiras linhas do resultado ficam assim

```
t p/ v=1  lead v=1  lead diff v=1     t p/ v=0  lead v=0    lead diff v=0
20.8806   (null)    (null)            (null)    (null)      (null)
20.8764   20.8806   -0.0042           (null)    (null)      (null)
20.87     20.8764   -0.0064           (null)    (null)      (null)
20.8636   20.87     -0.0064           (null)    (null)      (null)
20.8508   20.8636   -0.0128           (null)    (null)      (null)
20.85     20.8508   -0.0008           (null)    (null)      (null)
(null)    (null)    (null)            20.8333   (null)      (null)
(null)    (null)    (null)            20.8303   20.8333     -0.003
(null)    (null)    (null)            20.83     20.8303     -0.0003
(null)    (null)    (null)            20.8      20.83       -0.03
(null)    (null)    (null)            20.5      20.8        -0.3
(null)    (null)    (null)            20.4964   20.5        -0.0036
```