# Consultar valores duplicados na mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Estou com dificuldades em fazer uma consulta para exibir valores duplicados na mesma tabela.

Tenho uma tabela de registro de medições elétricas com os seguintes campos:

```
ID_EQUIPAMENTO, DATA, HORA, FASE_A, FASE_B, FASE_C
```

Independente da `DATA` e `HORA`, preciso identificar registros iguais na `FASE_A`, `FASE_B`, `FASE_C` em equipamentos diferentes, salientando que são muitos equipamentos.

segue imagem pra ilustrar melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Certo, e até agora, o que você já tentou ? Adicione o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso deva ajudar. Eu teria sido mais específico se você tivesse fornecido mais informações. Basicamente o que você precisa é determinar um referencial referente aos registros não únicos que quer monitorar, e em uma sub-querie verifica-los através de um `COUNT()`, agrupando de maneira conveniente.

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Referencial in
(SELECT Referencial FROM Tabela GROUP BY Referencial HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Entendi a consulta mas ainda não é isso, provavelmente não expressei minha duvida claramente, mesmo assim obrigado!

Comment: @RodriggoSantana, algo que pode ajudar é você criar um modelo do resultado esperado. Algo como o que foi feito [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/345502/como-simular-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-lead-e-lag-mysql). Aguardo suas edições.

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração suas informações (algumas superficiais) vou supor uma solução, acredito que já seja o necessário para o seu caso.

Você pode utilizar o [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) onde você pode utilizar funções agregadas.

Segue um exemplo para você adequar e implementar para o seu problema:

*Nesta tabela vamos imaginar que tenha somente os campos `COD_PRODUTO` e `DESCRICAO` e ainda que contenha registros **duplicados ou triplicados ...***

```
SELECT COD_PRODUTO, DESCRICAO FROM PRODUTOS
GROUP BY
    COD_PRODUTO, DESCRICAO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Caso tenha um produto que esteja "cadastrado" mais de uma vez no banco, ele será retornado nesta instrução acima.

Espero ter ajudado.